# Why i am getting "Bad Request" error while using Gmail Api?

Tags: wpf, api, service, gmail, account

i'm working wpf application.I want to delete email from all account in domain.
I'm using service account wide delegetion for this.

i also use  [here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#service-account) for authentication and other methods. I gave all permission for my admin account.

```
public GmailService GetService()
{ var certificate = new X509Certificate2(@"xxxxxxxxxxxx- 
fc9fcdc65959.p12", "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
           new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
           {

               Scopes = new[] { GmailService.Scope.MailGoogleCom }
           }.FromCertificate(certificate));
        GmailService service = new GmailService(new 
BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = AppName,
        });
        return service;
    }
```

List Function is below.

```
public static List<Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.Data.Message> 
ListMessages(GmailService service, String userId, String query)
    {
        List<Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.Data.Message> result = new 
List<Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.Data.Message>();
        UsersResource.MessagesResource.ListRequest request = 
service.Users.Messages.List(userId);
        request.Q = query;

        do
        {
            try
            {
                ListMessagesResponse response = request.Execute();
                result.AddRange(response.Messages);
                request.PageToken = response.NextPageToken;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: " + e.Message);
            }
        } while (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(request.PageToken));

        return result;

    }
```

When i try to list all emails, i'm getting this error.

```
"Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
Bad Request [400]
Errors [
Message[Bad Request] Location[ - ] Reason[failedPrecondition] 
Domain[global]
]"
```

İs anyone there to help me?

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]

Comment: i edited my question with more details @Hille

Comment: This edit was definitely an improvement. And If you have found an answer yourself, then please write an answer yourself with an explanation for future developer which have the same problem :) you can hit the accept as answer button afterwards to visualize that the problem was solved with this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a user account like:

```
ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer constructor = 
    new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail) 
    { 
        user = user_email; 
        Scopes = new[] { GmailService.Scope.MailGoogleCom }
    }.FromCertificate(certificate));
```

Comment: What does the `.Initializer` do compared to the `ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential` in your original code?